# distance travelled by a ball under the action of a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, energy-conservation, work

I was trying a question which goes like this:

**Two balls of same mass are projected, by compressing the springs of different force constants k<sub>1</sub> and k<sub>2</sub> by equal magnitude. The first ball is projected upwards along a smooth wall and the other on the rough horizontal floor with coefficient of friction $\mu$. If the first ball goes up by height h , then find the distance covered by the second ball in terms of k<sub>1</sub>, k<sub>2</sub>, h and $\mu$**

Since the question is based on springs, I tried to use the work done by spring, gravity and friction and get the answer but ended up with quite a long expression involving m and g terms as well. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

**My try:**

Work energy theorem being applied to the first case
$$\frac{1}{2}k_1x^2 - \frac{1}{2}k_1h^2 - mg(x+h) = 0$$
Work energy theorem being applied to second case
$$\frac{1}{2}k_2x^2 - \frac{1}{2}k_2y^2 - \mu mg(x+y) = 0$$
where y is the distance travelled by the second ball. I proceed by solving for x and substituting in the other equation, but however I get the mg term in the answer as well though the answer is not supposed to be in terms of mg.

PS: Moreover, I have a  doubt regarding the principle of working of spring. the work done by a spring which is compressed by a amount x to be elongated till its elongation is an amount x is zero. Is this correct?

Comment: Show us what you've done.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hope my edit matches the expectations of the site to ask a specific query. Thanks @JohnRennie

Comment: Is the answer k2•h/(mu•k1) ?

Comment: @HyperBean yes that is the given answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use energy conservation. For the first spring the only relevant energy at the beginning is stored in the compressed spring. When the ball reaches the highest point, all energy is transformed to potential energy. Hence you have

$$\frac{1}{2}k_1x^2 = mgh$$

For the second spring, the situation is the same at the beginning, but now we lose the energy due to friction:

$$\frac{1}{2}k_2x^2 = \mu mgd$$

Eliminating $x^2$ and solving for $d$ will give you the answer.

It seems to me that you were on the right track, but got confused when equating the energies. In both equations you have two terms for the energy stored in the compressed spring. Why? You also introduce $y$, without saying what it is. It will definitely help to make a sketch to understand the problem better.

Comment: is 'h' the height difference between the ball's initial position and final position? Similar, is 'd' the distance between the ball's initial position and final position?

Comment: Yes. Although, the ball is not in the final position `h`, but when it reaches the highest position.